# Why play.google.com make handshake only with SNI = google.com

Tags: ssl, certificate

Can't open https://play.google.com on my mac (safari and chrome) get ERR_TIMED_OUT, but can open on other laptops.
Looks like the server doesn't reply on ClientHello then SNI is same as host.

```
$> openssl s_client -connect play.google.com:443 -servername play.google.com
CONNECTED(00000006)
...endless loading here
```

work only if I set SNI google.com

```
$> openssl s_client -connect play.google.com:443 -servername google.com
CONNECTED(00000006)
depth=3 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS CA 1C3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=*.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS CA 1C3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS CA 1C3
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS Root R1
 2 s:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS Root R1
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
---
```

Answer (score 1):

> work only if I set SNI

It is pretty common that sites require SNI today, i.e. all sites were multiple domains with different certificates are hosted on the same IP - like everything behind Cloudflare.

> ... other devices can connect.

I assume with this that you mean that you can connect from other devices without explicitly given the `-servername` option. Use of SNI in s_client is the default for newer versions of openssl, instead they have a `-noservername` option to switch this default off. So likely you are using different versions of openssl on the different systems. Check with `openssl version`.

Comment: `$> openssl version     
LibreSSL 2.8.3
`
about other devices I mean that I can open play.google.com in a browser on other laptops, but can't on mac (safari and chrome) get ERR_TIMED_OUT

Comment: @saneery: the browser always uses SNI, so this is unrelated. It might be that you have some proxy settings on the system, where the proxy does not work. openssl s_client does not care about thus proxy setttings, only the browser.

Comment: yes, actually the browser set SNI = play.google.com, but it doesn't work. It works only with SNI = google.com. 
I have not any proxy and vpn.

Comment: @saneery: works perfectly for me with SNI play.google.com. On a Mac, with LibreSSL 2.8.3. Maybe there is some DPI solution (i.e. firewall or similar) on your machine or in your network which blocks access to play.google.com